# JQuery Datepicker for 3 textboxes date

Tags: jquery, textbox, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am currently working on JQuery Datepicker for 3 textboxes.
The logic should be :

- date of txtFrom can't be earlier than txtTo
- date of txtEstimate can't be earlier than txtFrom

The first logic is working but the second is not working, need advice on this issue.
Below are my codes.

```
       $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
          minDate: -60,
          onClose: function () {
              $("#txtTo").datepicker(
                "change",
                { minDate: new Date($('#txtFrom').val()) }
        );
          }
      });
      $("#txtTo").datepicker({
          minDate: -60,
          onClose: function () {
              $("#txtFrom").datepicker(
                "change",
                { maxDate: new Date($('#txtTo').val()) }
        );
          }
      });
      $("#txtTo").datepicker({
          minDate: -60,
          onClose: function () {
              $("#txtEstimate").datepicker(
                "change",
                { minDate: new Date($('#txtTo').val()) }
        );
          }
      });
      $("#txtEstimate").datepicker({
          minDate: -60,
          onClose: function () {
              $("#txtTo").datepicker(
                "change",
                { maxDate: new Date($('#txtEstimate').val()) }
        );
          }
      });
```

Comment: ` $("#txtTo").datepicker({})` datepicker instance initiated twice. Give it another Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoke the same method twice `$("#txtTo").datepicker`

Try:

```
$("#txtFrom").datepicker({
    minDate: -60,
    onClose: function () {
        $("#txtTo").datepicker(
        "change",
        { minDate: new Date($('#txtFrom').val()) }
        );
  }
});
$("#txtTo").datepicker({
  minDate: -60,
  onClose: function () {
      $("#txtFrom").datepicker(
        "change",
        { maxDate: new Date($('#txtTo').val()) }
       );
      $("#txtEstimate").datepicker(
        "change",
        { minDate: new Date($('#txtTo').val()) }
       );
  }
});
$("#txtEstimate").datepicker({
  minDate: -60,
  onClose: function () {
     $("#txtTo").datepicker(
            "change",
            { maxDate: new Date($('#txtEstimate').val()) }
    );
}
});
```

Comment: Hi Juan, I am facing an issue regarding this, code is not working on IE? It can work on Chrome. Can you advise on how to make it work on IE as well??